# mypy "is not valid as a type" for types constructed with `type()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

mypy complains `error: Variable "packagename.Foo" is not valid as a type`

```py
Foo = type('Foo', (), {})
Bar = Optional[Foo]
```

This error can be fixed by defining the type as a class:

```py
class Foo:
    pass

Bar = Optional[Foo]
```

Is there any other way around this? I need to keep the type definition dynamic.

Comment: why do you want to use `type()` like that?  note that `mypy` doesn't run/evaluate code so I don't think `type` would be executed to "make a new type object"

Comment: I guess it comes for the fact that mypy [can't handle dynamic base classes](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2477).

Comment: Note that the above link provides a workaround: `Foo = type(...) # type: Any`. (I'm not sure which specific type is required; `type: type` does not work.)

Comment: Generally, a static type checker is not going to be able to handle dynamically created types.

Comment: What I don't really understand is that if you "promise" the type checker that your variable will be of the class type `a: Type[Foo] = Foo`, why doesn't it consider valid `class Bar(a)`? We can do this in TypeScript without any problem: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQqBmBXAdsALgJYD2O0okEAYmAcQE4CeAFKBAFzT6MAOApsQxwAlIlTRy4KNABC0PgA98fHABMYbMeJToJ9Pviz0yMgNyo0qYKQj5Z0ALyTKNOk2axh5oA

Comment: As @chepner suggests, `# type: Any` is the only sane answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest that the difference is that `class`, as a syntactic construct, *must* produce a type, whereas `type` can be rebound to any callable at runtime. However, the `class` statement can also be modified by specifying a different metaclass. In the end, keep in mind that `mypy` is really a hack (in the best sense of the word) trying to squeeze as much static typing as possible out of the inherently dynamic data model that Python is based on. There are many corner cases it has to work around.

Comment: another sane answer might be to refactor so that you can use an Enum

Answer (score 8):

How about this, as a workaround?

```
from typing import Optional, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class Foo: pass
else:
    Foo = type('Foo', (), {})
    
Bar = Optional[Foo]
```

`typing.TYPE_CHECKING` is a constant that will always be `True` at compile-time, and will always be `False` at runtime. In this way, we can keep MyPy happy by only telling it about the static definition, but at runtime we can be as dynamic as we like.

You should be aware, though, that this is very much a workaround rather than a solution. By doing it this way, we are essentially lying to the type-checker about the true definition of `Foo`. This means that MyPy may fail to spot errors in some places, and may raise errors where none exist in other places. Dynamically constructing types at runtime is very useful in some situations, but goes against some fundamental principles of type-checking in Python, so you'll have trouble getting a type-checker to approve what you're doing without some kind of a hack.

Comment: In my use case I have a class factory function that returns a class (`var=class_factory()`). This was the only approach I could find to get mypy to accept `var` as a class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related mypy [issue 8897](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8897). In my case given this example:

```py
Bla = type("Bla", (), {})  # type: ignore[valid-type, misc]        

class Foo(Bla):
    pass
```

I could convince mypy to accept `Bla` by explicitly typing the LHS of the assignment:

```py
Bla: type = type("Bla", (), {})
```

Tested only with `mypy 1.3.0 (compiled: yes)`.