# How to annotate `dictview` type to satisfy mypy?

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy, python-typing

Let's consider an instance check for `dict_keys` type :

```py
dict_keys = type({}.keys())
print(dict_keys)  # <class 'dict_keys'>
assert isinstance({}.keys(), dict_keys)
```

According to Python documentation `.keys()`, `.values()` and `.items()` all return a dictionary view which is codified in documentation as [`dictview` view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views). However there seems to be no `dictview` type at least not in cPython implementation:

```py
# same output across Python 3.7 - 3.11
print(dict_keys.mro())              # [<class 'dict_keys'>, <class 'object'>]
print({}.values().__class__.mro())  # [<class 'dict_values'>, <class 'object'>]
print({}.items().__class__.mro())   # [<class 'dict_items'>, <class 'object'>]
```

I have a use case where I need to accept native `dictview` but reject user-provided objects which quack like `dictview` (duck-typing is not an option by design). I can do this by separately checking for `dict_keys`, `dict_values` and `dict_items`, but mypy complains on:

```py
dict_keys = type({}.keys())
# main.py:1: error: Need type annotation for "dict_keys"  [var-annotated]
```

A closest exposed type is `types.MappingProxyType` which allows for user-created dict views. It is not perfect because it has some extra methods `mapping`, but close enough.  However, it does not work either:

```py
from types import MappingProxyType
from typing import Type

dict_keys: Type[MappingProxyType] = type({}.keys())   # error: Incompatible types in
#   assignment (expression has type "Type[dict_keys[<nothing>, <nothing>]]",
#   variable has type "Type[MappingProxyType[Any, Any]]")  [assignment]
x: dict_keys    # error: Variable "__main__.dict_keys" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]

len(x)
```

The first error shows that mypy is pretty well aware of `dict_keys` existence, but it still insists that I should manually annotate it.
The second error is not related to my core question (it is discussed in [mypy "is not valid as a type" for types constructed with `type()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594682/mypy-is-not-valid-as-a-type-for-types-constructed-with-type)). [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=626a6431d7f90ecd203689e04208cb80).

Is there an obvious solution that I am missing, or should I head to mypy repo and open an issue? Of course I could just use `Any` but this is not the kind of solution I am looking for.

Comment: [`collections.abc.MappingView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MappingView) and [`collections.abc.KeysView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.KeysView)

Comment: `types.MappingProxyType` is completely wrong. It's barely even related to key/value/item views.

Comment: Yup, that's it thank you! Very obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @krassowski: It's not. Those are ABCs, which allow non-native dict views, contrary to your stated goals.

Comment: For example, [`collections.UserDict().keys()`](https://ideone.com/ZMiPyV) is an instance of `collections.abc.KeysView`, but not an instance of `type({}.keys())`.

Comment: Yes, but I can use them for type hinting `dict_keys: Type[MappingView] = type({}.keys())` and then use `dict_keys` and friends for instance checks. You are right that I cannot use `MappingView` for instance checks.

Comment: I am still a bit surprised that there is no runtime `dictview` though.

Answer (score 2):

Mypy does know of `dict_keys` - it's just contained in the internal `_collections_abc` module. But that shouldn't be no problem.
If you want to use `dict_view[str, int]` this problem becomes harder - but if you don't need to generic arguments it's quite simple.

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
   from typing import Union
   from _collections_abc import dict_keys, dict_values, dict_items
   dict_view = Union[dict_keys, dict_values, dict_items]
else:
   dict_keys, dict_values, dict_items = {}.keys(), {}.values(), {}.items()
   # if you're below 3.10 isinstance requires a tuple and doesn't work with unions
   dict_view = (dict_keys, dict_values, dict_items)
```

This should work so mypy complains about non-dict mapping views and that the `dict_*` types work for mypy and during execution.

```
def foo(view: dict_view):
    assert isinstance(view, dict_view)
```

Ping me if you need a generic `dict_view` as getting the correct behaviour with `isinstance` isn't trivial in that case.